# How to get page description with ruby mechanize?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

How do I get page descriptions with Mechanize?

The [Pismo gem](https://github.com/peterc/pismo) has this functionality, but it's worse than the [Mechanize gem](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize). Mechanize finds image tags, for example.

I didn't find in the [Mechanize documentation](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html) how to get the description.

Does anyone know a better plugin or how I can do that?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by page description? Where can I find this info on source of a page? Can you post an example?

Comment: Maybe the <og:description> meta http://embed.ly/docs/explore/oembed?url=www.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
node = page.at("head meta[name='description']")
description = node["content"]
```

(`node` is an `Nokogiri::XML::Node`.)

Comment: Use `page.at("head meta[name='description']")` instead of `page.search("head meta[name='description']")[0]`.